# React: Typescript/Javascript Interface as Callback and accessing state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

as a former Java Engineer I'm struggling to have an interface as callback in Typescript/Javascript.

I'm having a "worker" class where I call `doWork(..., myWorkerCallback)`
The callback consists of different callback methods.

```
interface WorkerCallback {
    onWorkDone() : void
    onError(message: String) : void
    ...
}
```

In my calling component I'd have a member that implements that Callback-Interface.

```
myWorkerCallback: WorkerCallback = {
    onWorkDone() {
    ...
    }
}
```

now I need to access the state of the React component inside these callback methods.
So I need to bind this callback member, right?
But how to bind this interface member

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about react-native but typical way to bind something to function is to use closures:

```
interface IWorkerCallback {
    onWorkDone(): void;
    onError(message: string): void;
    // ...
}

// Option 1: using object literals
function makeWorkerCallback(state: SomeState): IWorkerCallback  {
    return {
        onWorkDone: () => {
            state.update();
        },
        onError: () => { }
    }
}

// Option 2: using classes
class WorkerCallback implements IWorkerCallback {
    state: SomeState;

    constructor(state: SomeState) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    onWorkDone() {
        this.state.update();
    }

    onError(message: string) { }
}

// Usage example
const myWorkerCallback1 = makeWorkerCallback(state1);
const myWorkerCallback2 = makeWorkerCallback(state2);

const myWorkerCallback3 = new WorkerCallback(state3);
const myWorkerCallback4 = new WorkerCallback(state3);
```

Though at this point these objects are not callbacks. They are more. I would rename them "FooBarHandler" or something.

Comment: ok, so it seems I need to bind every individual function of the interface. there's no binding of an Interface instance.

Comment: I probably missing something in your problem. `makeWorkerCallback` will need to return all functions defined in interface. Not just `onWorkDone` (I will update my answer). So thus binding automatically happens for all functions.

Comment: Updated answer. If it is still not clear then I will need more detailed question with more examples.

Comment: thanks, but i need to access/bind the state of the react component, so just passing it in the constructor does not work i guess.